# Чем отличаются Components и Controls в VCL?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Допустим у нас есть форма или другой контрол (панель, фрейм, и т.п.). У них есть 2 очень похожих, но разных поля/списка - `Components` и `Controls`. Перечислите, чем эти списки отличаются друг от друга, как контролы в них попадают и в чем разница нахождения контрола в том или ином списке (или в обоих сразу)?

Comment: немного необычно видеть такой вопрос от человека, великолепно читающего по-английски ;-)

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: Простой, и в то же время полезный вопрос, для наполнения базы сайта. Заодно и тэг VCL создадим )

Comment: очень похоже на вопрос на собеседование. 
А так - очень простой ответ, что бы проверить собеседующего - любой Control - это Component, но не наоборот.

Comment: @KoVadim: Обратите внимание, вопрос про конкретные списки, а не про иерархию типов TControl и TComponent (хотя ее упоминание тоже будет являться частью хорошего ответа).

Comment: По поводу [описания метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26274): неплохо бы еще написать про ее использование: [Краткое описание метки - диссонанс между правилами и "практикой"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1096)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Определения.**

- Наследники `TComponent` называются "компонентами".
- Наследники `TControl` называются (обычно) "визуальными компонентами".
- `TControl` - прямой наследник `TComponent`, соответственно любой "визуальный компонент" (наследник `TControl`) является также "компонентом".
- Свойство `Components` для компонента `FooComponent:TFooComponent` (наследника `TComponent`) содержит все компоненты (наследники `TComponent`), такие, что `Owner = FooComponent`.
- Свойство `Controls` для визуального компонента `FooControl:TFooControl` (наследника `TWinControl`) содержит визуальные компоненты (наследники `TControl`), такие, что `Parent = FooControl`.

**Компоненты**. Наследники `TComponent`.

- Могут размещаться на палитре компонетов в IDE.
- Могут владеть другими компонентами, при уничтожении отвечая за уничтожение объектов, которыми владеет.
- Являясь наследниками `TPersistent`, могут копироваться, сохраняться, заполняться из потоков, файлов, других компонентов.
- Могут быть сконвертированы в ActiveX компонент, а также являться обертками над COM-объектами.

**Визуальные компоненты**. Наследники `TControl`.

- Имеют визуальное отображение в интерфейсе.
- Могут реагировать на интерактивные действия пользователя.
- у них есть размеры, позиция, видимость, всплавающие подсказки, и многое другое, влияющее на внешний вид...

**Визуальные компоненты, имеющие Handle**. Наследники `TWinControl`.

- Могут быть контейнерами для других визуальных компонентов.
- Могут получать фокус.

---

Вопросы

**Q** У меня есть форма `Form1:TFrom1`, что у нее будет в `Components`?
**A1** Все компоненты, которые добавлены в дизайнере форм.
**A2** А также те компоненты, которые в рантайме создаются в методах формы `TFooComponent.Create(Self)` или из других классов/модулей `TBarComponent.Create(Form1)`.

**Q** Для чего полезного можно использовать `Components`?
**A** Например, у вас есть несколько `TQuery` на форме, которые нужно разом все открыть (притом у них установлен `Tag:=1`):

```
for i:=0 to ComponentCount-1 do
  if (Components[i] is TQuery) and (Components[i].Tag=1) then
    TQuery(Components[i]).Open;
```

**Q** У меня есть форма, на ней панель, на которой две кнопки. Что у формы будет в `Controls`? А в `Components`?
**A1** В `Controls` панель. В `Components` и панель и кнопки.
**A2** А у панели в `Components` будет пусто, но зато в `Controls` будут кнопки.

**Q** Для чего полезного можно использовать `Controls`?
**A** Например, у вас есть несколько `TEdit` на панели, которые нужно разом все дизейблить:

```
for i:=0 to Panel1.ControlCount-1 do
  if (Panel1.Controls[i] is TEdit) then
    Panel1.Controls[i].Enabled:=False;
```

**Q** У меня есть форма. Все ли `Controls` будут также и в `Components`?
**A1** Если визуальные компоненты созданы в дизайнтайме, то да.
**A2** Чтобы визуальный компонент попал и в `Controls` и в `Components` при создании в рантайме, надо чтобы и `Owner` и `Parent` были этой формой:

```
btn:=TButton.Create(Self);
btn.Parent:=Self;
...
```

в остальных случаях `Controls` и `Components` будут отличаться составом вплоть до пустого пересечения этих множеств.

**Q** У меня есть форма. Все ли `Components` будут также и в `Controls`?
**A1** Маловероятно.
**A2** Если на форме нет невизуальных компонентов и они не создаются в рантайме, если визуальные компоненты размещаются непосредственно на форме, без вложенности на панелях, фреймах и т.д., если в рантайме визуальные компоненты создаются с `Owner` и `Parent` равными форме (и `Parent` в роцессе работы не меняется), то `Components` и `Controls` будут эквивалентными. Только смысл?

**Q** А можно создавать компоненты, в том числе визуальные, при этом чтоб они не добавлялись в `Components` формы?
**A1** Можно, тогда придется заботиться об их уничтожении самостоятельно, иначе память будет течь.
**A2** Можно создавать компоненты с `Owner=nil` (т.е. `TFooComponent.Create(nil)`), и после использования вызывают `Free`, такое использование ничем не отличается от других классов, которые не являются компонентами. Создал - удали.
**A3** Можно создавать компоненты с `Owner=Panel1` (т.е. `TBarControl.Create(Panel1)`) или привязав его другому компоненту (как на форме, так и непривязанному к ней). Но так делать не стоит, никто не поручится, что время жизни панели будет больше, чем у добавленного компонента, как следствие большая вероятность получить AV.

**Q** У меня есть форма и куча панелей вложенных, групбоксы там разные... Как мне достучаться до *всех* `TEdit` на всех панелях?
**A1** Ищите их через `Components` формы.
**A2** Возможно стоит подумать о других методах манипуляции, например, воспользоваться `Action`'ами. Ведь на форме может быть сотня компонентов, и три-четыре `TEdit`'а искать по такому списку смысла не много...

Answer (score 2):

**Components** - список объектов, для которых компонент является владельцем (Owner). По этому списку происходит уничтожение объектов когда текущий объект уничтожается.

К примеру мы создаем Button и указываем Owner'a. В данном случае Button попадет в список Components:

```
Button := TButton.Create(OwnerForm);
```

**Controls** - список объектов, которым компонент является родителем (Parent) и он отвечает за их отображение.

К примеру мы создаем Button и указываем Parent'a. В текущем примере кнопка Button будет отображаться на форме в позиции 10,10:

```
Button.Parent := OwnerForm; 
Button.Left := 10;
Button.Top := 10;
```

Comment: Controls - По этому списку ТОЖЕ происходит уничтожение объектов когда текущий объект уничтожается.